# Cache each element separately.

Tags: html, http

Is there are any ways to cache each element separately instead of giving meta tag to the full html page.Like each img tag having its own cache control attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The [HTML5 application cache](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp) can be used to specify which of a page's resources should be cached and which should not.  Unfortunately, the application cache does not provide the fine grain control that the HTTP cache control header provides, like parameters that determine under what circumstances the cached object will be considered stale.